# symphony datasource error

Tags: http-status-code-404, datasource, errordocument, symphony-cms

When creating a data source that pulls from any of my sections and pressing "create data source", I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /symph-page/symphony/blueprints/datasources/new/ on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Strangely, if I pull from the system or provide custom xml, the data source is created fine and I don't get the previous message. Running symphony 2.3 on server that should be meeting the technical requirements. I have run Symphony before and never encountered this sort of issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to change the `workspace/data-sources` directory file permissions so that the web server user can write files into it.

For example, on a Linux server (777 may not be necessary and depends on your webserver's configuration):

```
chmod 777 /symph-page/symphony/blueprints/datasources
```

If you access the server via FTP, your FTP client will probably let you do this.

Edit: Re-reading your question, I think I was mistaken in saying this is a workspace writing permissions issue. I don't recognise the "blueprints" directory path. Does this directory exist within your installation, and does your webserver have read permissions?

Comment: /symph-page/symphony/blueprints/datasources is not a real directory, I assume it is a url generated by mod rewrite. The url happens while navigating the back-end of symphony. However, workspace/data-sources is a real directory. I'll check its permissions now

Comment: alright changed permissions to the workspace/data-sources folder. Didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to make sure that you .htaccess file is present.